# Structure information for pcre

Tags: c, regex, pcre

I have the following function to compile a [`pcre`](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcre_compile.html) regex:

```
/**
 * common options: PCRE_DOTALL, PCRE_EXTENDED, PCRE_CASELESS, PCRE_MULTILINE
 * full options located at: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pcre_compile.3.html
 */
pcre* pcre_compile_pattern(const char* pattern, int options)
{
    const char *pcre_error;
    int error_offset;
    pcre *re_compiled = pcre_compile(pattern, options, &pcre_error, &error_offset, NULL);
    if (re_compiled == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: '%s' occurs at pattern position %d\n", pcre_error, error_offset);
    }
    return re_compiled;
}
```

Is there a place where the `pcre` struct is described? For example, I'm looking to see if it contains the `pattern` (as a normal string) inside it or whether I have to keep the pattern separately. I've seen a lot of references in the man pages to `pcre*` but I haven't really been able to get more details on that struct.

In searching github here was one place I was able to find it, which seems like it might be what I'm using: https://github.com/luvit/pcre/blob/e2a236a5737b58d43bf324208406a60fe0dd95f4/pcre_internal.h#L2317. Everything is private though so you cannot access part of the struct, for example to read/print it directly.

Comment: You should be using pcre2 in new code. And it's an opaque object that can only be accessed via the library api.

Comment: But no, you don't need to keep a copy of the pattern string after compiling it.

Comment: @Shawn thanks for pointing that out. Where can I download the `pcre2` library from? It seems my machine has `pcre` but not `pcre2`.

Comment: The pcre homepage is https://pcre.org Or if using an OS with a package manager, install it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a place where the `pcre` struct is described?

The include file defining the interface is `pcre.h` for version 1 or `pcre2.h` for version 2.

Much in the same way that we don't need to know how stdio's FILE struct is designed, we don't need to know how pcre is defined. We also will not need the pattern after we have received a pcre struct.

Shawn, in comments, pointed out the importance of using pcre2 for new code. It is also noted on the website: [pcre is end of life with 8.45 the last version, use pcre2 for new projects](http://www.pcre.org/).

The primary change for pcre2 is more aggressive pattern validation.

A demonstration of pcre2 is [available here](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2demo.html).